# Presto compare timestamp column as bigint giving different result

Tags: sql, timestamp, presto, unix-timestamp, bigint

I'm trying to figure out all data after a certain time(2021-12-31)

However, it gives different result when using these two clauses:

`cast (ann_updated_at as bigint) > 1640995199000`

and

`date_format(from_unixtime(cast(ann_created_at as bigint) / 1000), '%Y') >= '2022'`

What could be the reason here?

Comment: And what is the value which behaves this way?

Comment: I have tried and don't see any thing wrong with the functions you mentioned. Can you share few sample values for ann_updated_at where you see this issue?